# Does posix_fallocate work with files opened with appened mode?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I'm trying to preallocate disk space for file operations, however, I encounter one weird issue that posix_fallocate only alloates one byte when I call it to allocate disk space for files opened with append mode and file contents are also unexpected. Has anyone known this issue? And my test codes are,

---

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include  <sys/stat.h>
#include  <cerrno>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
     FILE *fp = fopen("append.txt", "w");
     for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
          fprintf(fp, "## Test loop %d\n", i);
     fclose(fp);
     sleep(1);

     int  fid = open("append.txt", O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);

     struct stat  status;
     fstat(fid, &status);
     printf("INFO: sizeof 'append.txt' is %ld Bytes.\n", status.st_size);

     int  ret = posix_fallocate(fid, (off_t)status.st_size, 1024);
     if (ret) {
         switch (ret) {
         case  EBADF:
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: %d is not a valid file descriptor, or is not opened for writing.\n", fid);
            break;
         case  EFBIG:
              fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: exceed the maximum file size.\n");
              break;
         case  ENOSPC:
              fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: There is not enough space left on the device\n");
               break;
         default:
               break;
        }
     }

     fstat(fid, &status);
     printf("INFO: sizeof 'append.txt' is %ld Bytes.\n", status.st_size);

     char  *hello = "hello world\n";
     write(fid, hello, 12);
     close(fid);

     return 0; 
 }
```

---

And the expected result should be,

```
## Test loop 0
## Test loop 1
## Test loop 2
## Test loop 3
## Test loop 4
hello world
```

However, the result of above program is,

```
## Test loop 0
## Test loop 1
## Test loop 2
## Test loop 3
## Test loop 4
^@hello world
```

So, what's "^@"?

And the message shows,

```
INFO: sizeof 'append.txt' is 75 Bytes.
INFO: sizeof 'append.txt' is 76 Bytes.
```

Any clues?

Thanks

Comment: `^@` probably indicates a NUL byte (`'\0'`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Quick Answer

Yes, posix_fallocate *does* work with files opened in APPEND mode. IF your filesystem supports the `fallocate` system call. If your filesystem does not support it the glibc emulation adds a single 0 byte to the end in APPEND mode.

### More Information

This was a strange one and really puzzled me. I found the answer by using the `strace` program which shows what system calls are being made.

Check this out:

> fallocate(3, 0, 74, 1000)               = -1 EOPNOTSUPP (Operation not
>   supported)
>   fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=75, ...}) = 0
>   fstatfs(3, {f_type=0xf15f, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=56777565,
>   f_bfree=30435527, f_bavail=27551380, f_files=14426112,
>   f_ffree=13172614, f_fsid={1863489073, -1456395543}, f_namelen=143,
>   f_frsize=4096}) = 0
>   pwrite(3, "\0", 1, 1073)                = 1

It looks like the GNU C Library is trying to *help* you here. The `fallocate` system call is apparently not implemented on your filesystem, so GLibC is emulating it by using `pwrite` to write a 0 byte out at the end of the requested allocation, thus extending the file.

This works fine in normal write mode. But in APPEND mode the write is always done at the end of the file so the `pwrite` writes one 0 byte at the end.

Not what was intended. Might be a GNU C Library bug.

It looks like ext4 does support `fallocate`. And if I write the file into /tmp it works. It fails in my home directory because I am using an encrypted home directory in Ubuntu with the ecryptfs filesystem

Comment: Indeed, this is a glibc bug. I'll report it.

Comment: Yes, my system doesn't support fallocate. Though, it seems to be a Glibc bug.

Comment: +1, this should be the accepted answer. Like Duck said you did the detective work and found a mildly-serious glibc bug (see my bug tracker link for why it's more serious than it looks at first).

Answer (score 1):

Per [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_fallocate.html):

> If the offset+ len is beyond the current file size, then posix_fallocate() shall adjust the file size to offset+ len. Otherwise, the file size shall not be changed.

So it doesn't make sense to use `posix_fallocate` with append mode, since it will extend the size of the file (filled with null bytes) and subsequent writes will take place after those null bytes, in space that's not yet reserved.

As for why it's only extending the file by one byte, are you sure that's correct? Have you measured? That sounds like a bug in the implementation.

Comment: I've measured a lot times and every test shows same behavior. It is really wield. Also, you can compile my codes on your side and test its behavior.

Comment: @tianya - I ran your pgm and did not see your results.  File size was 1099.  The loop stuff, bunch of binary zeros and then hello world.

Comment: @Duck - you can check Zan's comment.